# How to change shape and style of chrome extension pop-up?

Tags: html, css, reactjs, google-chrome-extension

So I am basically trying to build a chrome extension. Although I am able to change to styling inside the pop-up, I am not familiar with how to change the styling of pop-up window.

I have googled the problem and I see most of the people agree with we can't change the styling as it is controlled by Chrome. But then I see extensions like `Fonts Ninja` or `Rayst` which have their own custom styled pop-up. So now I am really curious, how they did it?

[image: Fonts Ninja's Pop Window]

[image: Rayst Pop-up Window]

Comment: Have you tried applying styles in body?

Comment: As you can see in devtools it's not the built-in popup, but just a DOM element in the current page, so you can do the same: remove `default_popup` from manifest.json and use onClicked event in the background script to inject the UI, [simple example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70870192).