# Chrome Extension iFrame

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I created a React app and would like to convert it to a chrome extension with iframe.

I didn't find any tutorials regarding this matter.

When a user clicks on the extension's icon, I want the extension to be injected as iframe on the right side of the page, overlaying on top of the current page.

Like SimilarWeb extension if someone knows it.

Can someone please explain me how to do it?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: See [Create iframe using Google Chrome Extension manifest v3](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70870192)

Comment: @wOxxOm Thanks! Indeed I get an iframe, but unfortunately it is empty. it shows only a small square with nothing in it, and when inspecting it, the body is empty.

Comment: You probably didn't reload the extension after adding web_accessible_resources to manifest.json. Either way, debug it in devtools.

Comment: @wOxxOm After long investigation, I needed to add the localhost as a src to the iframe, and make sure that it runs. Thank you!